# Using document.getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript

I coded two lines of PHP that allow me to protect an email address.

```php
$mymail=strrev($mymail);
$mymail=str_replace("@","<b>@</b>",$mymail);
echo "<span class='spdefense'>".$mymail."</span>";
```

totiko@gmail.com becomes `moc.liamg<b>@</b>okitot` in source code
The problem is that users can no longer copy and paste e-mail addresses transformed in this way. So I want to create a javascript function that allows on a ctrl+c to:
Reverse string and remove `<b>` tags around @ for all email adresses on a page.
No matter to reverse string and replace `<b>` tags. Mail adress is inside a span element with a class.

```js
longueur=document.getElementsByClassName("spdefense");
for(var i= 0; i < longueur.length; i++)
{
    machaine= document.getElementsByClassName("spdefense")[i].textContent;
    machaine.split().reverse().join();
    machaine.replace("<b>@</b>", "@");
}
```

I looked at "copy" and "clipboard" but I can't produce a valid code, to tell the truth I'm not sure if can be done...

Comment: you should declare longeur and especially macahine variables with const to make sure they are contained in scope.

Comment: I am very curious to know how the mentioned code is protecting the email.

Comment: You can't make an email address "protected" (though any web crawler with half a brain is going to decipher that in no time) and both readable by a human. The crawler bots are using the same mechanism to view the data as a human. Basically your wasting your time, either add a contact form or just use your email address and use a spam filter

Comment: @Liam - Granted, this won't protect against web crawlers with half a brain. But it will still protect against all the (very many) web crawlers with no brain at all.

Comment: Unlikely........

Comment: Why don't you use an encoding (like base64), or some kind of encryption (like AES)? There's no way crawlers can decrypt AES (even with a hardcoded key).

Comment: @HirasawaYui - This is going to be displayed on the client... What good is an encrypted email address that no one can use?

Comment: `This is going to be displayed on the client` - decode, render the string on a canvas and show as an image.

Comment: Of course I use rtl property in css. So every client see well formated mail adress...

Comment: @LiamNope ! Such a simple solution effectively protects the email addresses of a large majority of robots. Moreover nothing prevents for example to reverse only the first 3 characters then the two following @ etc...

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

- You want to re-use the `longueur` variable, as that's more efficient than grabbing all the classes twice.
- You want to define it in the local block scope, not in the global one, using the `const` keyword.
- You want to use the spread operator `[...]` to convert the string to an array of characters.
- You want to join on an empty string `.join('')`, as the default for `join` is to use commas `,`.
- You want to save the result back to a variable.
- You want that variable, `machaine`, to also be block scoped, rather than globally scoped.
- You want to export the result out of the loop somehow, using an array, `output`, in the below example, seems appropriate.

```
const longueur = document.getElementsByClassName("spdefense");
const output = [];
for(var i = 0; i < longueur.length; i++)
{
    const machaine = [...longueur[i].textContent].reverse().join('');
    output.push(machaine.replace("<b>@</b>", "@"));
}
console.log(output);
```

That should work a little better... I haven't tested it, but it seems right.

As for the copy & paste, you can take a browse of the [API documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API) over at MDN.

The long and short of it is that you can use something like:

```
function setClipboard(text) {
    const type = "text/plain";
    const blob = new Blob([text], { type });
    const data = [new ClipboardItem({ [type]: blob })];

    navigator.clipboard.write(data).then(
        function () {
        /* success */
        },
        function () {
        /* failure */
        }
    );
}
```

On a button click, which will add whatever `text` is, to the users system clipboard. There are permission considerations to take in to account, but chrome has it enabled by default (IIRC).

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very familiar with Stackoverflow UI, I answered the next answer and not yours. Thanks for this solution, it learns me some javascript news (example : push. I always redeclare my variable...).

Answer (score 0):

You can write to the `clipboard` via:

- `navigator.clipboard.writeText()`

Consequently, when a user copies an email address, you can:

- grab the obfuscated contents of the `<span>` which registered the `copy` event
- deobfuscated those contents
- write the deobfuscated contents to `navigator.clipboard`

---

**Working Example:**

```js
const obfuscatedEmail = document.getElementsByClassName('obfuscated-email')[0];

obfuscatedEmail.addEventListener('copy', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let deobfuscatedEmail = e.target.textContent.split('').reverse().join('');
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(deobfuscatedEmail);
});
```

```css
textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<h2>Copy and Paste the obfuscated email below:</h2>

<span class="obfuscated-email">moc.liamg<b>@</b>okitot</span>

<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: Many thanks for this detailed answer !

I try to understand your code, I'm not very familiar with javascript. I will give you a more detailed answer in a few hours.

Comment: The thing which you likely won't know is the `e` parameter - that represents the `event.object` in javascript. The `event.object` will tell you all sorts of things, like the type of event, which element the event applies to, when the event was initiated, whether the event was initiated by a user or computationally etc. (all this from `e` !) In this case, we are using `e` for two things: 1) to prevent the default event action from taking place, using `e.preventDefault()` and 2) to determine  the element the event applies to, using `e.target`.

Comment: You should also know that - in this scenario at least - the `.textContent` property is grabbing the text but ignoring the *HTML Markup*. Which is why I'm not replacing `<b>` with anything: by grabbing just the text, the string I now have is already markup-free.

Comment: You've probably understood `myString.split('').reverse().join('')` correctly, but just in case it's unclear, this series of methods turns a string into an array, with every array element representing a single character of the string; then reverses the array, then joins the array back into a string again.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the details. Indeed the syntax `(e) => {is` unknown to me and I did not know that textContent did not take tags. I've tried everything and I don't see why my code isn't working. Certainly obvious for a javascript specialist, but, for me... 

`const longueur=document.getElementsByClassName("spdefense"); 
for(var i= 0; i < longueur.length; i++) 
{ longueur[i].addEventListener('copy', (e) => { e.preventDefault(); let delongueur = e.target.textContent.split('').reverse().join(''); navigator.clipboard.writeText(delongueur); }); }`

Comment: In your code above, use `let i= 0;` instead of `var i= 0;`. You need to declare the variable `i` with block scope, not function scope.

Comment: A thousand times thank you. Looks like nothing you saved me. The last time I really worked with JavaScript was...in 2001. I had really tried everything and I was a little sorry to come and bother you again !